# Processing -- moving image leaving trail

Tags: java, image, processing

I'm working on trying to make an image move in processing, but the image is leaving a trail. The important part which is tripping me up is that I cannot declare the background in draw(), because I have other functions which place images. Here is the relevant code:

```
    void setup()
{
  size(752,500);
  background = loadImage("prairie.jpg");
  background(background);
  noStroke();

  animal = loadImage("squirrel.png");
  bird = loadImage("bird.gif");
  rock = loadImage("rock.png");
  cloud = loadImage("cloud.png");
  jeep = loadImage("jeep.png");
  flower = loadImage("flower.png");
}

  float jeepX = 752;
  float jeepY = 250;
  float size = 100;

void draw()
{
  image(jeep,150,350,125,125);

  image(jeep,jeepX,jeepY,size,size);

  jeepX--;
  jeepY = jeepY + .25;
  size += .25;
  image(jeep,jeepX + 1,jeepY - .25, size -.25, size - .25, 0,0,0,0);


  if(jeepY > height)
  {
    jeepX = 752;
    jeepY = 250;
    size = 100;
  }
        }
```

This is for lab and the TA didn't know how, and I didn't have a chance to ask the professor yet.

If no one knows the answer and/or it has something to do with other functions (which place images), i'll post the relevant code.

Comment: I find it slightly hard to follow. As far I understand you want an image as the background, but the first image you draw is set to take 125x125 only while the sketch spans 752x500 so there will be trails unless you clear the background. Can you maybe add a visual cue to what you're tying to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

For moving objects not to leave a trail, you must first clear the frame before redrawing the picture.(don't forget to reset the background if you don't have one)

As it is, it draws one jeep, then another on top of it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't reset the background, "because I have other functions which place images". I need a way to simply erase images hat I place.

Comment: Perhaps you could draw a blank image the color of the background on the image? A little hackish, but should work.

Comment: The background is an image, although maybe I could try to hack it together where it takes a section of the background the size of the image i'm trying to erase. I don't know how to manipulate images in Processing, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the trail, you got clear the background. If not completely, at least part of it, or redraw every image not supposed to move every frame.
Like this:

**Sample Code**

```
PImage bg, still, moving;

void setup() {
  while ( bg == null) {// got wait as size depends on this...
    println("loading bg image...");
    bg = loadImage("http://dc489.4shared.com/img/f9EaWk5w/s3/13757197c08/Black_Background_Metal_Hole_-_.jpg");
  }
  size(bg.width, bg.height);
  still = loadImage("http://www.renderosity.com/mod/bcs/photos/Thumb85619.jpg");
  moving = loadImage("https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/humano2/128x128/apps/alienblaster.png");



}

void draw() {

  background(bg);
  image(still, 100, 100);
  image(moving, 200,  frameCount%height);

}
```

Comment: Hm, okay. I'm thinking about setting it up so that the functions take variables for the image placement, and they redraw everytime draw() runs. I feel like that would be kind of cpu intensive for how simple the program should be.

Comment: Just occurred me another path, use PGraphics to make layers, so you only redraw moving images... But if the program is that simple, maybe the performance is not so important...

Comment: PGraphics sounds like a good suggestion. Also, instead of the while loop you can use [requestImage](http://processing.org/reference/requestImage_.html) which starts a new thread behind the scenes and doesn't 'lock' the main animation thread.

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Thanks for the requestImage thing. I frequently bypass new functions... But in this case, as I need the image to set size, wouldn't  that break the program?

Comment: @v.k. oh yeah, you're right, you would still need to wait for the image to load and initialize. Unfortunately [isLoaded()](http://processing.org/reference/javadoc/core/processing/core/PImage.html#isLoaded()) didn't work for me but checking if the image width & height did. In your case, because size() resets quite a few things(not just the size of the frame), the while loop is better :) my bad

Comment: Thank you all! I'll give PGraphics a shot. I've taken a look at it before but haven't been able to get it working. I'll try it again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to redraw your background in the 'draw' method. To do this, simply add the following line of code to your 'draw' method:

```
background(red,green,blue);
```

You can use the Colour Selector in Processing (found under Tools) to find the correct rgb code for the colour you want.

The reason for this is that the draw method is run 60 times a second, whereas the 'setup' method is only run once when the program is executed. As such, when you move the image, if the background colour is not in the 'draw' method, then it will not be redrawn when the image is moved, thus leaving a trail.

Comment: "The important part which is tripping me up is that I cannot declare the background in draw(), because I have other functions which place images."

Comment: @user3303354 You need to call these methods in the draw function so that they are redrawn with the background.